# ENOENT, no such file or directory 'bower_components/ember-addons.bs_for_ember/dist/js/'

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am using **ember-pagination** and when I run **ember serve** I get following error:

It says: `"ENOENT, no such file or directory 'bower_components/ember-addons.bs_for_ember/dist/js/"`

[image]

Versions:

```
$ node-v
V0.10.25
$ npm -v
1.3.10
```

Still searching for a solution but I cannot find it..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [ember-pagination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-pagination) or [ember-cli-pagination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-pagination)? If you're not using the CLI version I'd give that a spin first :)

(also you might want to update your NPM version. Anything 1.x is sorta broken)

Let me know if you run into any issues with ember-cli-pagination! I've contributed a bit to the code base and use it in one of my projects.

EDIT: Squinting at the screenie shows you're using the cli version. Can you post your brocfile.js?

Comment: Can I see the `Brocfile.js`?

Comment: well i fixed that issue :) and it was not ember -pagination it was ember-cli-pagination . Thanks for your comment.